# VBA | Looking for code to automatically number 'Page x of xx' in PowerPoint, while not numbering hidden slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking for a code that will 
(1) auto number 'Page x of xx' in PPT
(2) not count the hidden slides

If I have a 20 slide PPT, with 3 slides hidden, I would like to see 'Page 1 of 17' instead of 'Page 1 of 20'.

Thank you!

Comment: At Stackoverflow you will find held and assistance with programming issues, **but** we will not do your work for you. Show what you have tried so far and what is not working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for complete code without any attempt.